# Moto mock_s3 EndpointConnectionError, Connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, moto

I am trying to mock my S3 connection with moto

```
@mock_s3
def setUp(self):
   self.s3_client = S3Client()
   self.s3_client.create_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
```

But i get the following errors:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:"http://localhost:4567"

or

ConnecConnection refused
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that i specified an endpoint in the resource call:

```
self.s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    endpoint_url=endpoint,
    use_ssl=use_ssl,
    region_name=region,
)
```

Removing endpoint_url or just setting it to None solves the problem:

```
self.s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    endpoint_url=None,
    use_ssl=use_ssl,
    region_name=region,
)
```